# Aligning chart legends in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, legend

I'm not sure how to align the chart legends. Below is my stacked bar chart code I've tried, that adds the legends to the bottom left. I want to position the legend on the top right.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .chart-legend li {
           list-style-type: none;
        }

       .chart-legend li span { 
           display: inline-block; 
           width: 12px;
           height: 12px;
           margin-right: 5px;

       } 
</style>

<div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-6" class="thumbnail">    
<div  class = "thumbnail" style="width:100%" > 
  <h4>  <span class="label label-primary">{{ a.title }}</span></h4>
   <div>     
    <canvas id="canvas{{loopIndex}}" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
   </div>
 <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend">
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chartJS/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ChartStackedBar/src/Chart.StackedBar.js') }}"></script>

<script>

    var barChartData{{loopIndex}} = {
    labels : {{ serie.label | safe }},
    datasets : [
        {
        label: "Time Delay",
        fillColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.3)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : {{ a.data [0] }}
        },

         {
        label: "Devices",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: {{ a.data [1] }}
    }
]

}

var myfunction = function(){
    var ctx{{loopIndex}} =  document.getElementById("canvas{{loopIndex}}").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar{{loopIndex}}  = new Chart(ctx{{loopIndex}}).StackedBar(barChartData{{loopIndex}}, {
        responsive: true
    });
    document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = myBar{{loopIndex}}.generateLegend();       

}
allFunctions.push(myfunction);
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider posting your code as part of the post to make it easier to read. Also the images might be taken down somewhere down the line and if you include your code here your question can still be understood. You can format code by indenting all lines by four spaces. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks! I've done it :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?